# Jasminum Officinale a semi-evergreen?

Tags: evergreens

Many resources refer to the common white jasmine as a semi-evergreen, while technically a deciduous plant.

Does that mean the leaves remain green in temperate conditions? Or does it mean the plant loses its leaves only for a short time?

Comment: Agree with the answer you've had - even in London, Jasmine officinale loses its  leaves every winter, even in a mild winter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak for warmer climes, but I maintained a mature one in north London for twenty years. Every winter it lost all its leaves. According to the RHS [here](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/9454/jasminum-officinale/details), it's deciduous.